# Creating a generic search view in Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I am struggling to create my custom generic view in django to easily create search pages for certain models. I'd like to use it like this:

```
class MyModelSearchView(SearchView):
    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['name', 'email', 'whatever']
```

which will result in a view that returns a search form on GET and both form and results on POST.
The `fields` specifies which fields of `MyModel` will be available for a user to search.

```
class SearchView(FormView):
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        # what I'v already tried:
        class SearchForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = self.model
                fields = self.fields
        return SearchForm()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # perform searching and return results
```

The problem with the code above is that form will not be submitted if certain fields are not be properly filled. User should be allowed to provide only part of fields to search but with the code I provided the form generated with `ModelForm` prevents that (for example because a field in a model cannot be blank).

My questions are:

- Is it possible to generate a form based on a model to omit this behaviour?
- Or is there any simpler way to create `SearchView` class?

I don't want to manually write forms if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to set `blank=True` on the field in `MyModel`, as indicated in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> If the model field has `blank=True`, then `required` is set to `False` on the form field. Otherwise, `required=True`.

But for this to be a generic solution, you can't count on being able to modify the model fields.  You can instead set the fields' `required` attribute to `False` immediately after the instance is created:

```py
class SearchForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = self.model
        fields = self.fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for (field_name, field) in self.fields.items():
            field.required = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the ModelForm for searching, you should set all the fields as `required=False`, by overriding the `__init__` method:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    # what I'v already tried:
    class SearchForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = self.model
            fields = self.fields

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field in self.fields:
                self.fields[field].required = False

            return SearchForm()
```

Though I suggest you should user `django-filter`, which makes it easier and cleaner to filter your searches. First you need to install it:

```
pip install django-filter
```

Then add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. After that you can create a `filters.py` file in your app:

```
# myapp/filters.py

import django_filters as filters
from .models import MyModel

MyModelFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'whatever']
```

By default it's going to filter with the `__exact` lookup. You can change this in a couple of ways, just take a look [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters) and [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#generating-filters-with-meta-fields). To know which lookups you can use, take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

After creating your `filters.py` file you can add it to a View, like a ListView:

```
# myapp/views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .filters import MyModelFilterSet
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelSearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        filtered_model_list = MyModelFilterSet(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return filtered_model_list.qs
```

There's a lot more you can do with `django-filter`. Here's the full [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/).